# How to show Magento order review before payment process

Tags: php, magento

I'm developing a magento shopping cart. i haven't enough experience with magento. In default case in magento **'order review'** is placed after payment process , but i need to replce **'order review'** to before payment payment process. how can  i do this? can any one share any idea about it? or give any link for reference. thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "payment process"? what payment method are you using?

Comment: @Tim I'm using pay pal express checkout.
when i made payment with paypal and it comes back to my magento site . then i get order summery in magento and confirm place order button..
is there is any way to display order summery first and then payment processing

Comment: Sorry never worked with `pay pal express checkout`. With `paypal standard` you got redirected to paypal after the last step of the checkout which is "Order Review".

Answer (score 2):

For starters take a look in file **/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php**

Line 44: `$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');`

Obviously dont overwrite any core file and this is mainly a starting point, let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: when i changed to
array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review', 'payment');
it  is displayed as my desired order. but functionally it flows as default case , that means  still review process still at the final step .

Answer (score 0):

in the magento 1.7.0.2

/public_html/shoesales/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Abstract.php

line 208
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
//return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
return array('billing', 'shipping', 'review', 'payment');
}

this only changes the display order soon after billing (same shipping address option selected)
the step switches to payment